# angular shared module that distributes various @angular/material modules NullInjectorError: No provider

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-module

I have a uiModule. It imports and exports various @angular/material modules.

I had hoped that when I import `uiModule` in to `anotherModule`; now `anotherModule` will have access to @angular/material stuff... But that is not exactly working.

While material works fine inside the uiModule — `anotherModule` recognizes material elements however there are a lot of errors like

> NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken mat-menu-scroll-strategy!

> NullInjectorError: No provider for Overlay!

*I got those examples after trying to use `<mat-menu>`*

**Here is a look at the uiModule**

```
// material
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';

const material = [
  MatIconModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatProgressBarModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatChipsModule,
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  OverlayModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  ScrollingModule,
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PaginationComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ...material,
  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [
    PaginationComponent,
    ...material,
  ],
})
```

Comment: When you are on the official AngularMaterial page, there are several examples for each element. Also dxamples where you can hop to Stackblitz. There they use a similar like you.

https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fmaterial.module.ts

Maybe it will help

Comment: I have many working examples of material features. Im looking for help making a module so that material is installed in one module and that module is shared to other modules in need of material

Comment: Follow my link. That is exactly what you are looking for. In the example they have a separate module where all material dependencies are importet and exportet, and in the furhter doing they only reference this module

Comment: That link keeps redirecting to their home page. Any tips?

Comment: Sorry for that! I didn't notice. To solve navigate to stackblitz over the examples on the angular material page. Go straight to their page -> go to e.g. the menue-component -> in the first example (inside the box) which shows the menue button -> click on the 3. icon on the top right corner which will redirect you to stackblitz

Comment: There will be a module called "material.module.ts" ... This is what you ara looking for

Comment: did you export the module?

Comment: yes.. material is exported. you can see that in the original example

Comment: You got couple of responses and still ppl is confused about the actual error, my advice to you is share a reproducible repo like stackblitz and ppl will be able to understand better and help faster. @Omar

Answer (score 1):

The errors you see have a pattern, they are all errors regarding providers! The place where you are using a material component has some providers missing. Example: Overlay Provider.

The way components and services work is a bit different.

You can use a component (A) in another module (B) if you export the component A in it's module A and import the component's module in B. This needs to be done in every module you want to Use the component A.

But if module A requires a service it can be provided at the module level or at the root level. If you missing providing this you can get this error.

As you have not posted any code where you are using material components and facing the error, i will show a use case where this could happen.

Case:
`anotherModule` has a component which has a button in it's html which opens a dialog.

The dialog components are **not** rendered inside the component opening them. And they do have access to injector of `anotherModule`. So even though you have imported `uiModule` in `materialModule` if you have not imported in `AppModule` the No provider for XYZ errors can popup.

So try importing this `uiModule` in `AppModule`.

Comment: This is the best answer so far. Yes services are the problem. But how can i provide a material service at the module level?

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to build a module that exports all you need from material so just `import` and `export` material modules in that module.

Change `MaterialModule` Like below:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatIconModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    OverlayModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    ScrollingModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatIconModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    OverlayModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    ScrollingModule
  ],
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

Then add this in your `uiModule` where you declared the `PaginationComponent` or anywhere else.

---

But if you want to use `lazyLoading` correctly and as it supposed to, I suggest you to import each module where it is needed. If you do this, it will help you with the boot of your application because in order to load for example just a menu from material module, your app doesn't need to load all modules first.

Then you can use the below code in `app-routing.module.ts` too provide a better experience for your users:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: was not my answer helpful? @omar

Comment: Your recommendation is just another way of doing exactly what i have in my example... there are problems with both solutions related to services

Comment: if you want you can provide a stackblitz and I will debug it there.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the code added by you and there is nothing with wrong with the concept you mentioned. All the material modules will be available to the module which import it.

The only issues with the code is that you are missing two imports in your ui.module.ts

```
import {ScrollingModule} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import {OverlayModule} from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
```

After doing this, I would suggest you to run the command `npm install` to install all the dependecies. It will resolve the issue with the code.

Please let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: There are still problems with this approach. Same errors mentioned

Comment: What is the angular material version you are using in your application? Can you please check and let us know.